# How to convert bool array to byte?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I have following problem:
I'm reading 8 bit signal from one Arduino pin and store all informatin in bool array. Now I want to convert this array to single byte in decimal. How to do this?

I've tried this:

```
bool ID[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};
int recivedID = int(ID);
```

and

```
bool ID[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};
int recivedID = ID.toInt();
```

non works.

Comment: Why save it in a bool array in the first place? You could make a byte and set each bit individually. That will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this:

```
int recivedID = ID[0] | (ID[1] << 1) | (ID[2] << 2) | (ID[3] << 3) | (ID[4] << 4) | (ID[5] << 5) | (ID[6] << 6) | (ID[7] << 7);
```

which is the same as

```
int recivedID = 0;
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
   recivedID |= ID[i] << i;
}
```

I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte BoolArrayToByte(bool boolArray[8])
{
  byte result = 0; 

  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if(boolArray[i])
    {
      result = result | (1 << i);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```